# Where can i find some good critiques of a project I'm working on

Tags: projects

I need to get criticism of a personal project I'm working on (visually as well as on the code). I work alone and in fact don't really know anyone personally who *I trust* and is into coding & design.

Are there trusted communities where knowledgeable people offer **helpful** criticism on coding projects?

I see refactormycode.com, but I've never used it... There is so much junk out there, I hate to invest time in a community site that's not worth it. That's why I was looking for some great SO input.

*I build websites, with the occasional portable web application.*

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to contact freelancers for that purpose...A developer's perspective would be the best to judge from the functional as well as the behavioral point of view.

Cheers

Comment: right, but any ideas of communities of freelancers who look at each other's code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as constructive criticism on the visual side of things goes, I'd suggest [Concept Feedback](http://www.conceptfeedback.com/). I don't know if many people would willingly review the code to an entire website, but I think that if you're at the point where you want your code looked at you can probably review it yourself.